# Any Good Wordpress Client Like Live Writer To Create Static Pages

Tags: customization, windows-live-writer

I want to publish static pages on Wordpress quickly. Live Writer is a very good client for formatting and publishing blog posts. But I couldn't find a way to use it for publishing static pages.

Is there any way to publish static pages on Wordpress quickly with an easy to use client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following page Live Writer can manage pages as of Beta2.
http://en.support.wordpress.com/xml-rpc/windows-live-writer/

Maybe it's simply a case of waiting to use the newer version that includes page management?

I don't use WLW myself, but a quick google did garner the above link, so hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I had googled before asking here but I hadn't seen this. It looks enough for me.

Comment: Happy to help. :)